# Синапсы могут иметь только положительный весовой коэфицент?

Tags: нейронные-сети

[image: нейросеть]

Синапсы могут иметь только весовой коэффициент от 0 до 1? Или от -1 до 1?

Если 1, то нейрон возбужден и соответственно выходной синапс больше весит.
А если от -1 до 1, скажите как себя ведет -1?

По логике он вообще не должен участвовать. А значит по идеи ни на что не влияет? Или он уменьшает весовой коэффициент. Помогите пожалуйста прояснить в двух словах.

Comment: по графику всё видно же, -1 тоже может быть, но влияние минимальное.

Comment: @hitcode, а можете чуть более подробно рассказать. как именно влияет? если коэффициенты 0,3..0,97 то я просто их складываю и нахожу среднее значение. а что мне делать, если среди них есть -0,12?

Comment: @Anonymous точно так же складываете и находите среднее значение.

Comment: @yeputons, это точно? а то я ведь сложу. :)